# Run Ubuntu from NAND Orange Pi 2G IOT

Tags: 14.04

I want to boot my Orange Pi 2G IOT through NAND using Linux. Is there any way to run Ubuntu from NAND on this board? Thanks in advance!

I found this tutorial: http://surfero.blogspot.com.br/2017/09/orange-pi-iot-2g-flashear-memoria-nand.html

I followed the first three steps that are suggested, however I'm not able to see the device like is said: /dev/ttyACM0

I'm running it on Windows and using Putty to access the terminal.

How can I sucessfully run Ubuntu from this board's NAND?